# How to restream rtmp with python?

Tags: python, rtmp

How to restream\redirect incoming rtmp stream to several other services with python? Is it even possible with python?
I know that there is a nginx solution, but I need to change links for restream without restarting, so I want to use Python.

Comment: RTMP is just a binary protocol like any other? Have you tried using raw sockets?

Comment: @cricket_007 No, I did not use sockets. Is it really possible with this? If so, how do I look for information about restreaming using python sockets?

Comment: I don't know anything about rtmp. I assume it opens up a port, from which you can accept bytes and write those onto another listening port. It's not specifically a Python problem, as that's basically what nginx would be doing

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication

Comment: RTMP is not just a TCP connection. There are handshakes and keep alive packers that need to be handled.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, or corse it possible in python (or any other language for that matter) but it’s much harder.

Use nginx. Nginx can call your python code with the “exec” options. The. You can then spin up ffmpeg instances in python to restream wherever you want.